# Remove svn repository associated with ios project in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm a little bit confused with Xcode 5 Source Control options. I recently downloaded a project from Internet. That project had an svn repository associated and now I want to commit this project to one git repository hosted at bitbucket.

The problem is that I'm not able to see where is the option or what do I have to do to delete the association between the svn repository and the project. In the same way, I don't see where can I associate my bitbucket repository with the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer myself. First of all I deleted the .svn folder inside my project, after that I opened a terminal, I went to my project folder and I entered:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
```

After these steps I was able to upload the project to one bitbucket repo =)